# Guice equivalent of Spring's @Autowire list of instances

Tags: java, guice

In spring when I do:

```
@Autowire
List<MyInterface> myInterfaces;
```

then this list will get populated by all beans which implement `MyInterface`. I didn't have to create bean of type `List<MyInterface>`.

I'm looking for such behaviour in Google Guice.

Sofar I went with:

```
Multibinder<MyInterface> myInterfaceBinder = MultiBinder.newSetBinder(binder(), MyInterface.class);
```

Now if I have a bean which implements `MyInterface` and I bind it, say via:

```
bind(MyInterfaceImpl.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

it won't be included in my multibinder. I need to add:

```
myInterfaceBinder.addBinding.to(MyInterfaceImpl.class);
```

This is somewhat more complicated than what Spring offers. So I was wonmdering whether I'm not using it in wrong way. So is there easier way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it that way myself, yet, but according to Guice's API documentation, I think you should be able to write something not much more than this once:

```
bindListener(Matchers.subclassesOf(MyInterface.class), new TypeListener() {
  public <I> void hear(TypeLiteral<I> typeLiteral,
                       TypeEncounter<I> typeEncounter) {
    myInterfaceBinder.addBinding().to(typeLiteral);
  }
}
```

Then, when you bind an implementation via

```
bind(MyInterfaceImpl.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

it should be added to your multibinder automatically.

Comment: This is good point with the `TypeListener`, didn't come to my mind for this use case even though I used it earlier. Still there is some boilerplate as you would need to bind a `TypeListener` for every Interface. Way better than adding to the multibinder manually though (+1)

Comment: @JanZyka I guess, you can create map interface -> multibinder, bind a single listener matching everything and loop though the map. But how many such interfaces do you have so that you need such a big hammer?

Comment: Currently 1 to be honest ;) I just really like the spring way. It's so convenient. `@Autowire List<Interface> implementations;` and the magic just happens. I'm just surprised multibinders doesn't work in that way or there isn't equivalent for the spring behaviour. But as it seems there is not I accept your answer as it is closest to what I would expect to happen automagicaly. Note that in spring you can still declare named bean of type `List` if you don't want _all_ the interfaces. So I just think Spring handles this better.

Comment: I highly doubted if the above code would work as expected. I think when the  listener is triggered, the binding has already been completed.  That's said, `myInterfaceBinder.addBinding().to(typeLiteral);` would have no effect within a TypeListener registered by bindListner.

I wrote some code to verify my speculation, and the code turns out ``myInterfaceBinder.addBinding().to(...)` have no effect: the binding did not add to the set<MyInterface>.

Answer (score 1):

A hacky solution would be to do it all in a loop:

```
Multibinder<MyInterface> myInterfaceBinder
    = MultiBinder.newSetBinder(binder(), MyInterface.class);

Class<? extends MyInterface>[] classes = {
    MyInterfaceImpl,
    YourInterfaceImpl.class,
    MyCatsInterfaceImpl
};

for (Class<? extends MyInterface> c : classes) {
    bind(c).asEagerSingleton();
    myInterfaceBinder.addBinding.to(c);
}
```

It's hacky, it's applicable for such simple cases only, but it's simple and DRY.

Comment: I would consider this too manual but it's a bit better than doing it 100% manually :) +1