# Guice get multiple instances at a time

Tags: java, guice

I'm new to Java and Guice, but I am searching if it is possible.

For example, if a have the interface

```
public interface A {
}
```

and multiple implementations for that, which in a Guice module would be:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(A.class).to(Aimpl.class);
    bind(A.class).to(Bimpl.class);
}
```

I wanted to have something like that:

```
A[] implementations = injector.getInstance(A.class);
```

So I can use all implementations of the same interface!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `MultiBinder` :

In a module configuration :

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    Multibinder<A> aBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), A.class);
    aBinder.addBinding().to(Aimpl.class);
    aBinder.addBinding().to(Bimpl.class);
}
```

then, you can inject a Set of A :

```
public class MyConsumer {

  @Inject 
  public MyConsumer(Set<A> instances) {
  }
}
```

see https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings

Comment: Short addition: I can imagine the OP was looking for something like Spring or CDI where you can get all implementations of an interface injected automatically. This wont work, because guice does not scan the classpath, all bindings are either explicit or JIT. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404101/guice-classpath-scanning ... If you need such a feature, you will have to combine the approach in this answer with a manual classpath scan and add all bindings for found implementations.